# How to test if $I(\theta)\propto f(\theta)$?

Tags: distributions, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, binning

How do I test if a finite resource is distributed across a population proportional to the density function for that population?

Say $I(\theta)$ denotes resource allocation across $\theta$ (a known function) and $f(\theta)$ is the population density function. Say $\theta$ is split into $k$ bins. Proportion of $I$ allocated in bin $n$ is equal to total $I$ in bin $n$ divided by the total $I$ across all bins.

1. How do I test if this proportion is equal to the proportion of people in the same bin?
2. What would be a summary statistic that would indicate the degree to which $I(\theta)/\sum I$ deviates from $f(\theta)$?
3. Would a chi-squared test be proper, where Expected is dictated by $F$ and observed is $I$?